# return a subclass-type in java

Tags: java, class, return, subclass

I have a subclass "OnlineCourse". It´s a subclass of "Course". I want to return "OnlineCourse" in my class "Student". But instead of "EIST" I get back null.

Here´s what I have:

---

```
public class Student {

public String matriculationNumber;
public String name;
public int age;

public Course study() {
```

TODO 4: Comment the code below back in
Change the Course type to OnlineCourse and set its 
title to "EIST"
return the new course

```
    // Course course = new Course();
    // course.join();
    // return course;

    Course EIST = new OnlineCourse(); 
    EIST.join();
    return EIST;
}
}
```

---

Subclass that extends course and should be initiated as the return type for "EIST" in the class Student.

```
public class OnlineCourse extends Course{
public URL livestreamUrl; 
public Course join() {
    System.out.println("joined the course " + title);
    return this; 
}
public Course drop() {
    System.out.println("dropped out of the course" + title);
    return this; 
 }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class Course {

public String title;
public String description;
public LocalDate examDate;
public List<Lecture> lectures;

public abstract Course join();
public abstract Course drop();
}
```

---

Main- Method:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    var student = new Student();
    student.matriculationNumber = "01234567";
    student.name = "Joe Doe";
    student.age = 42;
    student.study();
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when you call `study()` you got null?

Comment: @sc0der yes correct

Comment: How this? should return `OnlineCourse` object

Comment: could you put the full code

Comment: @sc0der I added the main-method. There´s really nothing more.

Comment: You have attributes in the abstract class and you must initialize them if you want to use that object. You creates an empty OnlineCourse, then call join which uses title but title is not initialized

Comment: @Wippo I'm a total noob. Thank you a lot, my friend.

Comment: You are welcome. I don't know if you did but i suggest you to google some basic tutorial about constructors so you can learn how to write a custom constructor and stop using the default one followed by all those student.attribute=value

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying the course title is showing as null. In which case you have to set it for it to print. I'd also note that where you have EIST - that's just a variable name, it can be anything and doesn't have any affect on any values.

If I were to guess, I think you'd want something like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var student = new Student();
    student.matriculationNumber = "01234567";
    student.name = "Joe Doe";
    student.age = 42;
    student.study("EIST");
 }
```

And in Course, you'd want a setter method for the title like, -

```
public setCourseTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

And in Student

```
public Course study(String courseTitle) {
    Course EISTCourse = new OnlineCourse();
    EISTCourse.setCourseTitle(courseTitle);
    EISTCourse.join();
    return EISTCourse;
}
```

Comment: Since title is public he doesn't need a setter method. In this scenario he should write proper constructors and not use the empty-default one.